# Cannot execute an indented line of code in a python function

Tags: python

I am learning python and was trying my first dummy project. I wrote a function, in which a user can continue the code execution if s/he types one of the values from the list, or stop the code, if s/he types the other value from another list. Here is the function

```
myList=['','','','','','','','','',]
def continueGame():
    options  = True
    optionList1=['Yes', 'Y','y','yes','YES']
    optionList2=['No','no','n','NO']
    userChoice = ''
    while userChoice not in optionList1 and userChoice not in optionList2:
        userChoice = input("Want to continue the game ? (Y,N) :")
        if(userChoice not in optionList1 and userChoice not in optionList2):
            print("This is not the correct option. Please enter either Y or N.")
            userChoice = ''
            
    if(userChoice in optionList1):
        #myList=['','','','','','','','','',] ---------->Code 1
        options =  True
    else:
        options =  False
        
    if options ==  True:                         -------> Code 2
        myList=['','','','','','','','','',]      -------> Code 2
    return options
```

`myList` is a list defined as a global **List**, whose values change in other functions, not described here . I have tried two methods. `Code 1`  and `Code 2` (in the code above). But none of them work. Even if the user hits Y or Yes, it does not execute either Code 1 or Code 2.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Seems like you are missing the global keyword. Check this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/ It has a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `myList` inside the `continueGame()` function is only the same as the `myList` variable at the top if you specify that it should be. In particular, you should insert `global myList` like this:

```py
def continueGame():
    global myList
<then the rest of your code>
```

That tells python that the myList variable inside the function isn't a new one, it's the one in the global scope.

Also, no need for that trailing comma in your lists.